# How can I set up a do - while (for ()) loop?

Tags: powershell

I'm not sure if there's just a more efficient way I could be doing this, or if combining a while and for loop even works, but how can I fix this to run the function only when every item in the for loop returns true?

```
$In = @()
While ($In[-1] -ne 'done') {$In += @(Read-Host 'Prompt')}

do {
    for($i=0;$i-le $In.length-2;$i++) {function($In[$i])}
   }
while (for($j=0;$j-le $In.length-2;$j++)
    {Get-Service ($In[$j]) | $_.status} -eq "Running")
```

With a $In array of names of various services, the do -while is supposed to restart each service in the array when any one of the services return a status "Stopped".

Comment: This is very convoluted. What is this supposed to be doing?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I tried to get rid of unnecessary information.

Comment: Given your intent I would do `'a','b','c' | ? {(Get-Service -name $_).Status -eq 'Stopped'} | Restart-Service`

Answer (score 0):

I'ld do it like this:

```
$In = @()
do 
{
 $c = (Read-Host 'Enter service name') 
 if ($c) { $in+=$c} 
}
while  ($c) #just a void input to end    

$in | where-object {(Get-Service -name $_ ).Status -match 'Stopped'} | Restart-Service
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe OT, but if you've got V3 on that system I'd do it this way:

```
Get-Service | sort Status | Out-GridView -Title 'Select services to restart' -OutputMode Multiple | Restart-Service
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(($ans = Read-Host 'Give me something') -ne 'done'){
    Restart-Service $ans
}
```